# Прижать img к низу p

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется такая струтура:

**HTML:**

```
<p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
<p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  float: right;
}
```

Вопрос: как мне прижать картинку внизу параграфа так, чтобы нижняя граница картинки выравнивалась по последней линии текста, независимо от количества текста в самом параграфе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь [принятой практики в отношении приветствий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7).

Comment: надо, чтобы нижняя граница картинки выравнивалась по последней линии текста?

Comment: @Streletz, спасибо за замечание, учту.

Comment: @lexxl, да, именно так. Чтобы текст обтекал картинку с любой из сторон. В моем случае, картинка прижата к правой стороне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content p{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  text-align: justify;
}

.content p img{
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
<p>
</div>
```

Как вариант с помощью FlexBox

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Спасибо за идею, Flexbox еще не использовал. Но немного не то, надо чтобы текст обтекал картинку.

Comment: @SuperHuman как вам такое решение http://codepen.io/kuatmus/pen/wMyQNa

Comment: годное решение, но есть косяк, при увеличении кол-ва текста, картинка растягивается :)

Comment: Так добавьте max-height сколько вам нужно, вопрос изначально не так понял, рад если помог :)

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо :) Еще подожду - может еще кто-то варианты предложит.

Answer (score 1):

Решение через `absolute`:

```
p {
  position: relative
  padding-right: 370px; // 350px ширина картинки + 20px отступ
  min-height: 150px; // минимальная высота картинки
  overflow: hidden;
}

p img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Решение через `inline-block` и `calc`:

```
p span { // оборачиваем весь текст (НЕ включая картинку) в тег span
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: calc(100% - 370px); // 370 аналогично 1му варианту
}

p img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

В обоих решениях мы точно знаем размеры картинки, а это значит что такое решение не лучшие для адаптивной верстки. Возможно для адаптивной верстки лучше использовать `js`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Первый вариант не подошел. Второй попробую.